# How do you group a table of strings using one column to group but aggregating on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The scenario is that I have a table that looks like this, with book IDs, their titles in English and/or French, and their sales. There are also some nulls. Some books will have only English or only French titles. Some may have multiple of both or either.

| ID | Title | Language | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Sorceror's Stone | English | 50,000,000 |
| 12345 | Philosopher's Stone | English | 50,000,000 |
| 12345 | A L'ecole de sorcier | French | 50,000,000 |
| 33333 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 67890 | A Christmas Carol | English | 65,000,000 |
| 67890 | Un Chant de Noel | French | 65,000,000 |
| 24680 | La Fascination | French | 30,000,000 |
| 24680 | La Crépuscule | French | 30,000,000 |
| 13579 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Basically, I want to narrow down this table as follows:

1. If at least 1 English title exists, we want the alphabetically first English title.
2. Else if at least 1 French title exists, we want the alphabetically first French title.
3. Else, just have string null.

I want my resultant table to look like:

| ID | Title | Language | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Philosopher's Stone | English | 50,000,000 |
| 33333 | null | null | null |
| 67890 | A Christmas Carol | English | 65,000,000 |
| 24680 | La Crépuscule | French | 30,000,000 |
| 13579 | null | null | null |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

Using `row_number` analytic window function:

```
with title as (
    select * , 
        Row_Number() over(partition by id order by case when [Language]='English' then 0 else 1 end, title) rn
    from t
)
select id, title, [language], Sales
from title
where rn=1
```

Comment: Windowing functions are almost always the answer to this kind of "arbitrarily de-duplicate records" problem, and some of the others like rank, dense rank, etc. are sometimes more useful.  For Asker's reference the "with * as" syntax is a CTE, and also usually needed in these cases since you sometimes must apply windowing or grouping on results.  It can be accomplished with subqueries but using CTEs is much easier to read, and also you can run the CTE by itself to debug or understand each step of the query.